# WebAPI Odata apply query options on typeless entity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm implementing a web api odata using a typeless entity. How can I apply the query options?

query options that consists of $filter, $expand etc.

Answer (score 0):

This sample illustrates typeless odata service: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataUntypedSample/